# How should I refer to the godmother of my child in formal documents?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

Is there a word such as *sister*, *spouse*, *aunt*, *cousin*, etc., which describes a person who is my child's godmother?

Informally, I would refer to this person as an aunt, but that implies a genetic relationship that does not actually exist.  I could formally describe her as *friend*, but I am hoping to find a more accurate term.

Comment: Why wouldn't it just be Mike's godmother?

Comment: Potential Mother Pro Tempore. Okay, maybe not, but it sounds good and has approximately the same meaning.

Comment: @Andy - what the hell does that mean?

Comment: Well, *Pro Tempore* is a Latin phrase used in (**edit** American) politics to describe someone elevated into a position but only until the situation is rectified. Most often used to describe someone who is temporary Speaker of the House, the *Speaker Pro Tempore.*  It's often the role of the godparents to take custody of the child in the case of the of the parents being incapacitated, but it because it's a hypothetical, I qualified it with *potential.*

Comment: @Chris Nielsen Referring to her as a "sponsor" would sound way too ambiguous.

Comment: @Andy - that is just confusing.  I would be confused.  The godmother isn't necessarily the person who would take over as a parent if the parent died.  My kids all have different godparents... They aren't going to all go to different homes.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd then what is the role of the godparents in your case? Is it just an honorific?

Comment: In my area it is traditional that a godparent introduces and helps a child with things like church and school.  An elder to "help" and be a friend or mentor.  I know that this isn't true in all regions.  But this is the norm in the midwest and if you had three kids it is normal for them to have three different sets of godparents.

Comment: That makes SO MUCH MORE SENSE than what I've always been led to believe it means.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd - Mike is not otherwise mentioned in the document. If I bring up Mike's name, I have to explain who Mike is.  By the time I do this, I may as well have just said "the godmother of my child" to begin with. I am looking for a more concise solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a legal concept but a religious and thus the terms reflect the purpose or spiritual nature, and tradition (IOW, women may not have been equal and ergo, no term other than godmother):

**[compeer](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mwc/85998/compeer)** :

> literally, **godfather**, from Medieval Latin compater, from Latin
>   com- + pater father — more at father Date: 13th century companion II.
>   noun Etymology: Middle English comper, from Anglo-French, from Latin
>   compar, from compar, adjective, like — more at compare Date: 15th
>   century equal, peer • compeer

The concept is **[compaternity](http://universalium.academic.ru/95431/compaternity)**: the relationship between the godparents of a child or between the godparents and the child's parents. Interestingly, the etymolgy is *[godmother](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=godmother&searchmode=none) or woman who sponsors one at baptism, late 13c. (n.1); modifying or replacing Old English godmodor* but the relationship would have been spiritual, and without guardianship implication

Just a note: the church now refers to both godparents as 'sponsors', and there is no legal association

Comment: In the 13th century women had effectively no property rights (In fact, women were levirated), and the duty off compaternity fell upon men.

Comment: If the masculine is *compeer* then I demand the feminine form be *compress*. Then, an emotionally distant godmother could be a *cold compress*.

Comment: @ Andy I'm reading 'Monsieur de Thou's History of his own time', and laughing so hard I cannot get back my train of thought -bad Andy ;-)